# How to instantiate a template class when constructor takes arguments

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, queue, instantiation

I'm trying to create a new object of the class `Queue<T>`, with the following:

```
Queue<char[40]> *q = new Queue<char[40]>(100);
```

Then, I want to use this `q` on another class constructor:

```
Interface<char[40]> i(q);
```

If I just use it, I get an error saying `invalid conversion from ‘Queue<char [40]>*’ to ‘int’`, which I figure means I'm trying to pass the value of q, which is the pointer to it instead of the actual value. Fine. Then I redefined the `Interface<T>` constructor to receive a pointer instead of the value itself, so the signature is

```
Interface(DataStructure<T>& q);
```

Since Queue extends DataStructure. For some reason, now the instantiation of `q` fails:

```
undefined reference to `Queue<char [40]>::Queue(int)
```

But I am quite sure I have written the constructor method WITH an INT parameter

```
template<typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue(int size): DataStructure<T>(size) {
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
}
```

Why the hell am I getting this error, then? To play with pointers is just getting a mess and I could not figure out by any means what to do now.

Comment: "undefined reference" seems to suggest you defined the constructor in a source file rather than in the header.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: On another note: this `char[40]` looks a bit suspicious. Perhaps you want to use `std::string` instead?

Comment: @dyp this constructor is defined in the header as `Queue(int size);`

Comment: Does that mean that you *did* define (= the block shown in your question; the definition of a function contains the function body `{ /*...*/ }`) it in the source file? This does not work for member functions of class templates. Please read the Q&A I've linked above.

Comment: @dyp okay, now it works. One more question: to use a template with `char[40]`, do I have to use pointers everywhere? If I want to return the value of something in a function, it complains I'm returning an array.

Comment: That's the trouble with array types. Please don't use pointers (this can easily lead to other problems). Rather, put the arrays inside class/struct types; you can also use `std::array` which does exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code `Queue<T>::Queue(int size)` suggests you put the definition in a source file. If you use templates all your code must be in the header file. (There are other approaches, but this is the easiest).